# Recursive function inside a simple loop time complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Why is it that inside a for loop and calling a recursive function results to the time complexity of **O(2^N)** not **O(N 2^N)** of this code below. Basing on the book CTCI.

```
void allFib(int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + ":  "+  fib(i)); 
    }
}

int fib(n){
    if  (n  <=  0)  return 0;
    else if  (n  ==  1)  return 1; 
    return fib(n - 1)  +  fib(n -2);
}
```

Comment: Because only the largest part is taken. The same reason iterating through an array twice gives ```O(n)``` complexity and not ```O(2n)``` complexity. The 2 is dropped.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi - then using your logic (exactly as stated) what about O(n Log n)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: @MichaelBianconi that is not correct. In big O notation you drop all constants, but there is a difference in O(2^n) and O(n * 2^n). You may not ignore a nonconstant multiplier.

Comment: @Maras You can ignore, because for large n, the `n` factor is almost irrelevant compared to the `2^n`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel lol that's not because of large n, that's because 2^0+2^1+...+2^(n-1) is smaller than 2^n. the non-constant factor should never be ignored no matter how large or how small it is

Comment: @MarkRotteveel the `n` term dominates `log n` in `O(n logn)`. We do not drop the `log n` term and we shouldn't drop it here either

Answer (score 2):

Think of your recursive function as computing values in a tree.

```
        fib(n)
         /\
        /  \
 fib(n-1)   fib(n-2)
```

If you look carefully for `n = 2`, there are `3` values to be computed which is `2^(1+1) - 1 = 3`  where `1` here is the height of the tree as in`2^(h+1)-1`

for `n = 3`, the height is `h = 2`

for `n = 4`, the height is `h = 3`

For all `n`, you need to add all of those:
`2^2 - 1 + 2^3 - 1 + 2^4 - 1 + ....2^n - 1` -> is of the order of `2^(n+1)`

Hence you get `O(2^n)`